# How to save piker's value to Realm db?

Tags: xamarin.forms, realm, picker

i am working with Realm and my example is similar to [this](https://github.com/BraxTV/xamarin-forms-master-realm-xamarin/tree/master/RealmAddressBook) one by @BenBishop . I added a Yes / No picker to my PersonPage and im trying to save the selected value of the picker to my db.  Could anyone help me with that please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a Realm question as that sample just uses Realm internally for storage. Most of its code is generic C# Xamarin code.

As a quick summary, you need to

1. Add a property in `AddEditPersonViewModel.cs`
2. Update `AddEditPersonViewModel.Init` to load the new property
3. Add a picker mapped to that property, in `PersonPage.xaml`
4. Add a matching property in `Person.cs` to store that value
5. Update `IDBService.SavePerson` to allow passing the new property
6. Update `RealmDBService.SavePerson` to copy the new property back to Realm

In detail:

```
// step 1 & 2
public class AddEditPersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
...
// added property
    private int superPower;

    public int SuperPower {
        get {
            return superPower;
        }
        set {
            superPower = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SuperPower"));
        }
    }
...
    public void Init (string id)
    {
    ...
        SuperPower = Model.SuperPower;



// step 3 - in PersonPage.xaml
        Text="{Binding LastName}" />
      <Picker SelectedIndex="{Binding SuperPower}">
        <Picker.Items>
          <x:String>Flight</x:String>
          <x:String>Super Strength</x:String>
          <x:String>Ordinariness</x:String>
        </Picker.Items>
      </Picker>
    </StackLayout>


// step 4 - in Person.cs
  public class Person : RealmObject
  {
  ...
      public int SuperPower { 
          get; 
          set;
      }


// step 5 in IDBService.cs
    public interface IDBService
    {
        bool SavePerson (string id, string firstName, string lastName, int SuperPower);


// step 6 in RealmDBService.cs
  public class RealmDBService : IDBService
  {
  ...
      public bool SavePerson (string id, string firstName, string lastName, int superPower)
    {
        try {
            RealmInstance.Write (() => {
                var person = RealmInstance.CreateObject<Person> ();
                person.ID = id;
                person.FirstName = firstName;
                person.LastName = lastName;
                person.SuperPower = superPower;
            });
```

Comment: A picker is a list selection control so the index is int. The labelling displayed on it might change as it is localised but the value would remain the same.